# How to authenticate with Kubeflow Pipelines API

Tags: kubeflow-pipelines

I'm hoping to experiment with triggering pipelines using the raw Kubeflow Pipeline API, but there is very little information about how to authenticate. All the information I can find in https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/pipelines/reference/api/kubeflow-pipeline-api-spec/ is:

> ### Security
>
> Bearer
>     Type: apiKey
>     --
>     Name: authorization
>     In: header

And when sending a request with an invalid bearer token, I know it expect a JWT, but I have no idea how to generate one.

```
Invalid IAP credentials: Expected JWT to have 3 parts separated by a '.' but there are 1 parts
```

Is it possible to do this without using `kfp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without 'kfp' is pretty messy and hard to automate.

anyway, [here](https://github.com/kubeflow/kfctl/issues/140#issuecomment-578837304) is one way

```
0) curl -v http://$SERVICE:$PORT

Response:
>> <a href="/dex/auth?client_id=kubeflow-oidc-authservice&amp;redirect_uri=%2Flogin%2Foidc&amp;response_type=code&amp;scope=profile+email+groups+openid&amp;state=STATE_VALUE">Found</a>.

STATE=STATE_VALUE

1) curl -v "http://$SERVICE:$PORT/dex/auth?client_id=kubeflow-oidc-authservice&redirect_uri=%2Flogin%2Foidc&response_type=code&scope=profile+email+groups+openid&amp;state=$STATE_VALUE"
Response:
>> <a href="/dex/auth/local?req=REQ_VALUE">Found</a>

REQ=REQ_VALUE

2) curl -v 'http://$SERVICE:$PORT/dex/auth/local?req=REQ_VALUE' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data 'login=admin%40kubeflow.org&password=12341234'

3) curl -v 'http://$SERVICE:$PORT/dex/approval?req=$REQ_VALUE'

Response:
>> <a href="/login/oidc?code=CODE_VALUE&amp;state=STATE_VALUE">See Other</a>.

CODE=CODE_VALUE

4) curl -v 'http://$SERVICE:$PORT/login/oidc?code=$CODE_VALUE&amp;state=$STATE_VALUE'

Response:
>> set cookie authservice_session=SESSION

5) curl -v 'http://$SERVICE:$PORT/pipeline/apis/v1beta1/pipelines' -H 'Cookie: authservice_session=SESSION'

Response:
>> 200 OK { ... }
```

Comment: thanks for the link. I no longer need the answer but I'll mark this as solved as the link looks like the better place to discuss/find out more.